Video glitching and gpio pin problems. Faulty Pi or low voltage?
I have 12 externally powered neopixels connected to one of the gpio pins of my RPi3B+ which in turn is powered by a (supposedly) 2.5A power supply and hooked up to a small 1024x600 LCD display (separately powered as well).
I am running into a strange issue where I can get the neopixels to animate via python normally and I can get a 720p h264 video to play using MPV normally but when I try to animate the neopixels and run the video at the same time, the video glitches out with red line artifacts and the neopixels glitch out as well by displaying random colors.
I regularly get the low voltage warning appear on the screen, could this be the root cause? Is starting the video at the same time as the pixels drawing too much power causing the voltage to drop and the behaviour to glitch? I thought that the pi would shutdown first if the voltage drops gets too low instead of the gpio pins glitching and video playback being affected. Top shows relatively low CPU usage and ram still available throughout.
I am going to try source an alternative power supply for the Pi but could it be the Pi itself which is defective?

yes, the possibility that the Pi is defective always exists ... the question cannot have a no answer ... I don't  see how that is useful information,  especially when you have not eliminated the power supply as the possible problem

As jsotola points out, it's impossible to say what the chances of the Pi being faulty are unless you have two set up identically, in which case if the behaviour is the same, probably not, and if it isn't and one is fine, then maybe the other is faulty.

I thought that the pi would shutdown first if the voltage drops gets too low instead of the gpio pins glitching and video playback being affected

Not exactly.  The voltage tolerance is generally stated as +/-5%, meaning it probably has to drop below 4.75 V to trigger a reboot because this is essentially the same as pulling the plug then putting it back in again. There's no mechanism to just shut it down until what? The voltage returns?  As just described, that's just (more or less) nature.
The warning is to alert you that you are approaching the threshold low voltage and risk triggering such an event.  It doesn't mean the system is handling this so everything will be perfectly the same until then.
Since the neopixels are powered from the Pi, it isn't surprising that they might be affected by the drop.  The 3.3V rail is regulated which might mitigate that, but the 5V rail is the 5V rail and that's where the voltage drop is being measured.
WRT video playback, there are parallel issues, eg., with people who use HDMI to whatever adapters that suck extra power -- sometimes these do not work even if the system voltage is fine.  HDMI is 5V, so if the 5V rail voltage drops then so will the HDMI.
Using a better power supply might help, but don't count on it much unless this is a Pi 5 and you are going up to 3A (which is still not a guarantee of anything).

Thanks for the detailed response. The pixels are actually not being powered by the Pi which is why I was thinking the behaviour is odd, they are being powered by a separate 1.5a 5V psu which is more than enough to power the 12 pixels.
I switched out the pi for another 3B+ and the video glitching issues went away, incidentally the voltage warnings disappeared as well but I switched to an official Pi power supply just in case.  The neopixels are still not working though, if I run the pixels before playing the video it works, as soon as the video starts the pixels "die" until I restart the pi.
